# Multiple jqGrid in Accordion view?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to create a dashboard of sorts. I was using Jquery's Accordion plugin and in each view have a grid using jqGrid. I wasn't impressed with what i came up with as it looked to bulky having a accordion box and with in it another grid. Is it possible to just have multiple jqGrids on the screen and use the expand/collapse button in the upper right of jqGrid to control a accordion type view with other grids?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override `click` event on this hidegrid button and force every other grid to hide (by triggering the `click` event ;) ). This is my first idea.

Perhaps there are some built-in events which I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("#Grid1").jqGrid({                        // 1st Grid
            url: 'service URL',
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['Id','MID','VendorCode1','VendorCode2','Percentage'],
            colModel: [
            {name:"id",index:"id",width:30},
            {name:"mid",index:"mid",width:30},
            {name:"vendorcode1",index:"vendorcode1",width:40},
            {name:"vendorcode2",index:"vendorcode2",width:40},
            {name:"percentage",index:"percentage",width:70}
        ],

    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,        // To Bind the Data in Grid.
        id: "id",
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },        // To Bind the Data in Grid.
        //page: function () { return 1; },
        page: function (obj) { return obj.length > 0 ? 1 : 0; },
        total: function () { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    },

            rowNum:20,
            rowList:[20,30,40,50],
            loadonce: true,       // If True, all pages will be loaded, else only 1 page will be displayed.
            pager: '#navGrid',
            sortable: true,
            sortname: 'mid',
            viewrecords: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            showOn: 'button',
            multiselect:true,   // Enabling Checkbox.       
            sortorder: 'asc', 
            prmNames: {rows: 'max'},
            height: 290,
            width: 1222,
            shrinkToFit: false,            // For Horizontal Scrollbar.
            toolbar: [true,"bottom"],      // For appending Buttons in Toolbar.
            rownumbers: true             // To display No.of rows.
    });
    jQuery("#Grid1").jqGrid('navGrid','#navGrid',{view: false,edit:false,add:false,del:false,refresh:true});


 $("#Grid2").jqGrid({                       // 2nd Grid
            url: 'service URL',
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['Id','MID','VendorCode1','VendorCode2','Percentage'],
            colModel: [
            {name:"id",index:"id",width:30},
            {name:"mid",index:"mid",width:30},
            {name:"vendorcode1",index:"vendorcode1",width:40},
            {name:"vendorcode2",index:"vendorcode2",width:40},
            {name:"percentage",index:"percentage",width:70}
        ],

    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,        // To Bind the Data in Grid.
        id: "id",
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },        // To Bind the Data in Grid.
        //page: function () { return 1; },
        page: function (obj) { return obj.length > 0 ? 1 : 0; },
        total: function () { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    },

            rowNum:20,
            rowList:[20,30,40,50],
            loadonce: true,       // If True, all pages will be loaded, else only 1 page will be displayed.
            pager: '#navGrid',
            sortable: true,
            sortname: 'mid',
            viewrecords: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            showOn: 'button',
            multiselect:true,   // Enabling Checkbox.       
            sortorder: 'asc', 
            prmNames: {rows: 'max'},
            height: 290,
            width: 1222,
            shrinkToFit: false,            // For Horizontal Scrollbar.
            toolbar: [true,"bottom"],      // For appending Buttons in Toolbar.
            rownumbers: true             // To display No.of rows.
       });
    jQuery("#Grid2").jqGrid('navGrid','#navGrid',{view:     false,edit:false,add:false,del:false,refresh:true})
 });
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#firstpane p.menu_head').click(function () {

        //slideup or hide all the Submenu

        //remove all the "Over" class, so that the arrow reset to default
        $('#firstpane p.menu_head').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('rel')!='') {
                $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('rel') + 'Over');              
            }
        });     
        //show the selected submenu
        $(this).siblings('div.menu_body').slideDown('fast');

        //add "Over" class, so that the arrow pointing down
        $(this).addClass($(this).attr('rel') + 'Over');
    });
});
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="menu_list" id="firstpane">
<p class="menu_head">Grid-1</p>
<div class="menu_body">
<table id="Grid1"></table>
<div id="navGrid1"></div>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<p class="menu_head">Grid-2</p>
<div class="menu_body">
<table id="Grid2"></table>
<div id="navGrid2"></div>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

1. We can use multiple Jqgrid in a single page (Different Grid-IDs) with either Click Event (Slide Up & Down Event) or Mouse Over Event.
2. Check above code, which I have used in my project. It works fine